# How can I have a fixed height for table cells in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox

How can I have fixed height for table cells in Firefox? The following works in IE and Chrome, but Firefox is not using the specified height:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Table Cell Height Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .overlay {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            table-layout: fixed;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;        
        }

        .overlay th {
            padding: 4px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .test {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

        .test th {
            padding: 4px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="overlay">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="height: 42px;">Staff</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <table class="test">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="height: 42px;">Staff</th>
                    <th style="height: 42px;">Monday<br>
                     27th</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The aim is to have overlay the same height as the test table.

One solution I have found is to wrap the cell contents in a div and set the height on the div.

Another solution I have found is using jQuery,

```
$('table.overlay tr').height($('table.test tr').outerHeight());
```

Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [height of a cell](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout) depends on the height requirements of its contents, and any `height` value set will be taken as imposing a *minimum* height. When the content is text, the height requirements depend on the number of lines of text and on the line height, which may vary by browser. So if you really want consistent rendering within some fixed (in pixels) area, you would need to set font size and line height in pixels (which implies problems of its own of course).

Comment: Well Firefox is not taking it as minimum height. It is rendering the cell has less height then the specified one. Hence my question

Comment: Looking at the white “Staff” cell in Firebug layout pane, I see content height as 33 (pixels), top and bottom padding both as 4, and bottom border as 1, making a total of 42. Some other browsers may treat the `height` property as setting a minimum on *content* height. If this causes undesired variation, I don’t think there’s a better option than wrapping cell contents in a `div`, setting any desired padding inside it, and setting table cell padding to zero.

Comment: yeah.. weird.. Shouldn't it be using box-sizing: content-box; ??